# How to use different convolution layers in different branches of tf.map_fn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I tried to establish a simple multi-head attention layer in tensorflow1.14. Each head contains three different `conv1d` layers. And I want to use tf.map_fn to compute parallel.

```
import tensorflow as tf

n_head = 50 # heads counts

conv1d = tf.layers.conv1d
normalize = tf.contrib.layers.instance_norm 
activation = tf.nn.elu

f1d = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 42),dtype=tf.float32) # input feats

f1ds = tf.tile(f1d[None, ...], [n_head, 1, 1]) # n_head copys to apply different attention heads

def apply_attention(f1):
    f1 = activation(normalize(f1[None, ...]))
    q = conv1d(f1, 32, 3, padding='same')
    k = conv1d(f1, 32, 3, padding='same')  # [1,ncol, 32]
    v = conv1d(f1, 1, 3, padding='same')  # [1,ncol, 1]
    attention_map = tf.nn.softmax(tf.reduce_sum(q[0, None, :, :] * k[0, :, None, :], axis=-1) / (32 ** .5),
                                  axis=0)  # [ncol,ncol]
    return attention_map * v[0]

f1d_attention = tf.map_fn(lambda x: apply_attention(x), f1ds, dtype=tf.float32)
```

But when I detect the variables in this model, it seems like there are only one group of `conv1d` layers in the whole model.

```
conv1d/bias/Adam [32]
conv1d/bias/Adam_1 [32]
conv1d/kernel [3, 42, 32]
conv1d/kernel/Adam [3, 42, 32]
conv1d/kernel/Adam_1 [3, 42, 32]
conv1d_1/bias [32]
conv1d_1/bias/Adam [32]
conv1d_1/bias/Adam_1 [32]
conv1d_1/kernel [3, 42, 32]
conv1d_1/kernel/Adam [3, 42, 32]
conv1d_1/kernel/Adam_1 [3, 42, 32]
conv1d_2/bias [1]
conv1d_2/bias/Adam [1]
conv1d_2/bias/Adam_1 [1]
conv1d_2/kernel [3, 42, 1]
conv1d_2/kernel/Adam [3, 42, 1]
conv1d_2/kernel/Adam_1 [3, 42, 1]
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you don't ant to use `tf.map_fn`. `tf.map_fn` will evaluate your function once, and run your different inputs through the same function, effectively using the same convolution layers for each input.

You can achieve what you want with a simple for loop :

```
# Creating a different set of conv for each head
multi_head = [apply_attention(f1d) for _ in range(n_head)]
# stacking the result together on the first axis
f1d_attention = tf.stack(multi_head, axis=0)
```

I've reduce the number of heads to 2 for visibility, but if we look at the variables, we see that 2 groups of convolution has been instantiated.

```
>>> tf.global_variables()
[<tf.Variable 'InstanceNorm/beta:0' shape=(42,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'InstanceNorm/gamma:0' shape=(42,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 42, 32) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 42, 32) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_1/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_2/kernel:0' shape=(3, 42, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_2/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'InstanceNorm_1/beta:0' shape=(42,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'InstanceNorm_1/gamma:0' shape=(42,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_3/kernel:0' shape=(3, 42, 32) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_3/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_4/kernel:0' shape=(3, 42, 32) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_4/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_5/kernel:0' shape=(3, 42, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv1d_5/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

---

**Side Note:** Unless you have a really good reason, you should migrate away from TensorFlow 1 and use TensorFlow 2 instead. Support for TF1 is limited.